# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

So im trying to return a DataTable via a Jquery Ajax call to a webservice but keep getting an error that the JSON being returned is not formatted correctly. When i pass the string into a validator it say's its fine, anyone know where im going wrong with this?
My code is below:

```
 var params = new Object();
        params.centreId = 0;
        params.brcWeek = 0;
        params.brcMonth = 0;
        params.brcYear = 0;
        params.weekOffSet = 0;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/Webservice/LloydsService/getLloydsOverview",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.debug("data received Ok?");
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + " -- " + "---" + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

web service:

```
 <WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function getLloydsOverview(ByVal centreId As Integer, ByVal brcWeek As Integer, ByVal brcMonth As Integer, ByVal brcYear As Integer, ByVal weekOffSet As Integer) As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim serializer As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()

    Using conn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = GetDBConnection()
        Using cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_LloydsDashboard_Overview"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CentreId", centreId)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BRCWeek", brcWeek)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BRCMonth", brcMonth)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BRCYear", brcYear)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WeekOffSet", weekOffSet)
            Using DA As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                conn.Open()
                DA.Fill(dt)
                Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
                Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
                For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
                    For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
                    Next
                    rows.Add(row)
                Next
                Dim json As String = serializer.Serialize(rows)
                Return json
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

which returns this (which validates):

```
[{"WalkedPast":1000,"PeelOff":0.1,"WalkedIn":100}]
```

but i still get the error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Abstract away the "web service". It's not relevant.

Comment: What exactly gives you the syntax error? The web service or the JavaScript processing the response (it sounds like the latter, but being clear never hurts)? What line of the code processing the JSON is throwing the error?

Comment: the response from the ajax call it goes straight to error - errorthrown shows alert box with the error thrown test SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: How are you checking what is being returned by the webservice? Are you examining the Net tab of the developer tools to see the response to the actual ajax request?

Comment: using firefox dev tools, checking console and response i get custom error page, but status code is a 302. so decided to output the error in a alert box.

Comment: Also by putting a breakpoint on the webservice and calling the webservice in the browser i can see the string response being returned

Answer (score -1):

don't stringify (assumed `params` is already json)

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/Webservice/LloydsService/getLloydsOverview",
            data: params,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.debug("data received Ok?");
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus + " -- " + "---" + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9vj8tk2z/), look into console.

Comment: `params` is **not** JSON. It is a JavaScript object. If the OP were to follow your advice then jQuery would automatically encode it but as form data, not JSON!.

Comment: ... and therefor jQuery is stringifying it internally. Otherwise its posting a string encpsed in json which causes the error. Thanks for downvoting w/o approval

Comment: How would sending form data instead of JSON solve a problem with a JSON parser throwing an error?

Comment: just tried what you suggested there but the error still remains i'm afraid